# Window less embeded exe within Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, firefox-addon

I have developed a firefox extension (add-on), and embed a c++ console application (.exe) in it. I pass command line arguments to that exe and it performs some actions associated with those arguments. Problem is whenever that exe is invoked a console window appears and disappears. I want that to be silent. Any thoughts?

Comment: How is the exe invoked? From javascript or c++? Do you have the source code for the c++ console app?

Comment: exe is invoked using `nsIProcess`, this interface is available within firefox extension (javascript). And yes I have source code for the console app as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually execute your executable via `nsIProcess` right now. Unfortunately `nsIProcess` does not give you enough control over the process creation to avoid the console window.

You'll either have to modify the console application itself, to be a "Windows" application not "Console" application (`WinMain()` vs. `main()`), or if that is not possible, you'll have to somehow call [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) yourself with `dwCreationFlags` including the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flags.

The latter can be either done by:

- Calling `CreateProcess` with appropriate flags directly, if your add-on code is already C++.
- Using [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) to import `CreateProcess`, define the necessary structures and call it, replacing your use of `nsIProcess`.
- Using another helper application, which is a "Windows" application, which will call `CreateProcess`  to launch your actual application with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Comment: yes i am using nsIProcess. Since I am new to C++ let me ask some beginner questions: Just changing the name of main method to WinMain() would work or need to do something else as well? And WinMain takes arguments?